# How to archive my on premise files once they are processed into azure data lake?

Tags: azure, filesystems, azure-data-factory

I have a pipeline activity which processes my on premise files inside file share into azure data lake. And then I have to automate the process of whenever the data is processed inside the data lake, I want to archive my source files.

STEP1: I have builtin a logic app which can automatically copy any new data from IN folder to OUT directory and delete the old files in IN directory.

STEP2: I have builtin my pipeline which processes data inside my Data lake.

Now how can I trigger my logic app inside my pipeline through some activity which will automatically delete my on premise files by calling my logic app ?

Please suggest

Comment: How to trigger a logic app from data pipeline?

Comment: On what basis I have been given -2..Like seriously?

Answer (score 0):

1. ADF Web Activity can be used to call a custom REST endpoint from a Data Factory pipeline. [enter link description here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-web-activity)
   And as far as I know,logic app can listen http request. So maybe you could chain a web activity after your data processing activity?
2. [ADF custom activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-using-dotnet-custom-activity) runs your customized code logic on an Azure Batch pool of virtual machines. So I think you could also put your trigger logic into custom activity?
3. Another way I could think is, maybe you could invoke your logic app based on some schedule? like daily or weekly?